# Pyspark - Iterate through string to extract multiple key value pairs

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I currently have a text string that is separated with ampersand that I need to parse using PySpark to extract the key-value pairs into an array/dictionary. I'm able to do this with most of the tags that I have in the string but the problem is that some keys have an index and this can vary per record but the keys will always be the same (if that makes sense. What I would like to do is, loop through the string

Example Input:

```
"{pr1nm=Apples&pr1id=1111111&pr1pr=200.00&pr1qt=1&pr2nm=Pears&pr2id=1111112&pr2pr=300.00&pr2qt=2}"
```

Desired output:

```json
[{
  "ProductName":"Apples",
  "ProductId": "1111111",
  "ProductPrice":"200.00",
  "ProductQuantity":"1",
  "ProductName":"Pears",
  "ProductId":"1111112",
  "ProductPrice":"300.00"
  "ProductQuantity":"2"
}]
```

Additionally, if I have other tags in the same string, which are not product relate e.g:

```
"{dl=https://stackoverflow.com/posts/XXXXX&t=pageview&pr1nm=Apples&pr1id=1111111&pr1pr=200.00&pr1qt=1&pr2nm=Pears&pr2id=1111112&pr2pr=300.00&pr2qt=2}"
```

the output should be something like this with the products in a nested array:

```json
{"DocumentLocation":"https://stackoverflow.com/posts/XXXXX",
  "HitType":"pageview",
   "Products": [{
                 "ProductName":"Apples",
                 "ProductId": "1111111",
                 "ProductPrice":"200.00",
                 "ProductQuantity":"1",
                 "ProductName":"Pears",
                 "ProductId":"1111112",
                 "ProductPrice":"300.00"
                 "ProductQuantity":"2"
               }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str_to_map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#str_to_map) to convert the string to map column like this:

```
df = df.withColumn("input", expr("ltrim('{', rtrim('}', input))"))\
       .withColumn("input", expr("str_to_map(input, '&', '=')"))

df.show(truncate=False)

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|input                                                                                                                          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[pr1nm -> Apples, pr1id -> 1111111, pr1pr -> 200.00, pr1qt -> 1, pr2nm -> Pears, pr2id -> 1111112, pr2pr -> 300.00, pr2qt -> 2]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then, if you want a JSON string, use [`to_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#to_json) function :

```
df.withColumn("input", to_json(col("input"))) \
  .show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|input                                                                                                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"pr1nm":"Apples","pr1id":"1111111","pr1pr":"200.00","pr1qt":"1","pr2nm":"Pears","pr2id":"1111112","pr2pr":"300.00","pr2qt":"2"}|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```